# Why do I get 404 on magmi/web/magmi.php for Magmi in Magento 2.3 - Lemp?

Tags: magento2.3, nginx, magmi, localhost, centos

After download magmi from https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2 ( Branch: magento2) and paste into root folder, then run **[www.giri.local/magmi/web/magmi.php](http://www.giri.local/magmi/web/magmi.php)**  getting 404 error page not found.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone help with this too please?

I have tried every possible combination i can find online relating to the nginx.conf file

Using Magento 2.3.4

1.
location /magmi {
root $MAGE_ROOT;

```
location ~ ^/magmi/.*\.php {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

2.

location ~ /magmi/(.*) {
root /srv/www/example.com/magmi;
try_files /web/$1 /web/$1/;
location ~ ^/magmi/(.*.php)$ {
try_files /web/$1 =404;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-example.com.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=2G \n max_execution_time=3600";
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600s;
include fastcgi_params;
}
}

3.

location /magmi {
root $MAGE_ROOT;

```
location ~ ^/magmi/.*\.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

Stuck with a capital "STUCK"

Cheers,
Joe